# how to show and hide inner divs onclick upto 3 levels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following structure in my page

**HTML:**

```
        <div style="position:relative; width:200px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
                <div style="position:absolute;" id="innerDiv">
                    <table style="width:400px;height:50px;" border="1" id="innerTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="td1"class="monthDiv" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                                    2000
                                </div>
                                <div id="td2" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                                <table>
                                    <tr><td id="quarter1">JAN-JUN00</td><td id="quarter2">JUL-DEC00</td></tr>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                               <div id="w" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                                    2001
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    $("#td1").click(function(){
        $("#td1").hide('slow');
        $("#td2").show('slow');
    });

    $("#td2").click(function(){
        $("#td2").hide('slow');
        $("#td1").show('slow');
    });
    $("#quarter1").click(function(){

        });
$("#quarter2").click(function(){

        });
```

So, when I click on `'td1'(2000)` I am showing `'td2'(JAN-JUN00 AND JUL-DEC00)'` and viceversa but I need to show another `div(JAN00 FEB00 ... JUN00)` when click on `'quarter1'`. Also I need to find on which `div` click event was fired, `'quarter1'` or `'quarter2'` to show `(JUL00 AUG00 ... DEC00)`

Please help me.

Comment: what should happen when `quarter1` is clicked and for `quarter2` ?

Comment: @TusharGupta for quarter1- JAN00 FEB00 ... JUN00 and for quarter2 - JUL00 AUG00 ... DEC00 to be display but when i click quarter1 both click events are fired(quarter1 and td2) since quarter1 is inside td2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call a `show` event on the `div` you want to display on click of `quarter1`:

```
$("#quarter1").click(function(){
   alert('quarter1');
   $('#quart1').show('slow');
});
$("#quarter2").click(function(){
   alert('quarter2');
   $('#quart2').show('slow');
});
```

`quart1` and `quart2` are the `id`s of the `div`s you want to display.

**EDIT:**

Add this:

```
$("#td1").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#td1").hide('slow');
    $("#td2").show('slow');
});

$("#td2").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#td2").hide('slow');
    $("#td1").show('slow');
});
```

Comment: but when i click  quarter1 both click events are fired(quarter1 and td2) since quarter1 is inside td2